# GTX 3.0 Grid Widget - How to refresh/reload a grid

Tags: java, grid, gxt, gxt-charts

I understand that grids work via stores, in my instance a ListStore. Is there a way I can make a call to the grid if I alter the store to reload/refresh the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
grid.getView().refresh(false);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: this doesnt appear to be working...any thoughts as to why not?

Comment: Let me get this clear, maybe I understand you in the wrong way. So, you add/remove some of your model data from your listStore that already bind to a grid. Then you want your change to be effected to your grid, right? The above code should do that. If you change the model data inside the listStore, make sure you call the update method in your listStore to commit your change. Post your code, so I can help you better. Thanks